# An issue concerning the Maximize command in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum, correlation, maximize

I have two sets. One set consists of constants and the other one consists of expressions depending on two variables "a" and "b". I find absolute values of correlations between the aforementioned two sets of values. I get the maximum value of 0.975 among these absolute values of correlations using the Maximize command over 1/4 <= a <= 3, -3 <= b <= -1/4:

`Input: Maximize[{Abs[Correlation[{5 2^(2 a + 3 b), 2^(1 + a) 5^b, 3 2^(2 a + 3 b), 2^a 5^b, 2^(1 + b) 3^a 5^b + 6^a 13^b}, {415.3, 407.85, 397.34, 396.04, 379.04}]], 1/4 <= a <= 3, -3 <= b <= -(1/4)}, {a, b}]`

`Output: {0.975188, {a -> 0.870869, b -> -3.}}`

However, I get the maximum value of 0.6785 among the considered absolute values over -3 <= a <= 3, -3 <= b <= 3:

`Input: Maximize[{Abs[Correlation[{5 2^(2 a + 3 b), 2^(1 + a) 5^b, 3 2^(2 a + 3 b), 2^a 5^b, 2^(1 + b) 3^a 5^b + 6^a 13^b}, {415.3, 407.85, 397.34, 396.04, 379.04}]], -3 <= a <= 3, -3 <= b <= 3}, {a, b}]`

`Output: {0.678523, {a -> 3., b -> 3.}}`

Certainly, the maximum value in the second case should be greater than or equal to 0.975188 (the one obtained in the first case) because of the constraints. I don't know where I am making a mistake. Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edited: The code suggested by user64494 worked fine for the initial example. However, I have now encountered another example where the code suggested by user64494 has the same issue as asked in the original question.**

The code

```
NMaximize[{RealAbs[
       Correlation[{12^(2 a + 3 b), 13^(1 + 2 a + 3 b), 2^(2 a + b), 7^(
         3 a + b), 11^(4 a + b), 13^( 
         a + 3 b)}, {-49.82, -51.5, -50.82, -50.69, -50.4, -53.71}]], -10
    <= a <= 10 && -10 <= b <= 10}, {a, b}, 
     Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

gives output

```
{0.96707, {a -> -1.43894, b -> 10.}}
```

However, if the constraint "-10 <= a <= 10 && -10 <= b <= 10" is replaced with "-3 <= a <= 3 && -3 <= b <= 3", the correlation increases:
that is, the code

NMaximize[{RealAbs[Correlation[{12^(2 a + 3 b), 13^(1 + 2 a + 3 b), 2^(2 a + b), 7^(3 a + b), 11^(4 a + b), 13^(a + 3 b)}, {-49.82, -51.5, -50.82, -50.69, -50.4, -53.71}]], -3
<= a <= 3 && -3 <= b <= 3}, {a, b}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

gives output

```
{0.972989, {a -> -1.41882, b -> 0.504752}}
```

Comment: `Maximize[{Abs[
   Correlation[{5 2^(2 a + 3 b), 2^(1 + a) 5^b, 3 2^(2 a + 3 b), 
     2^a 5^b, 2^(1 + b) 3^a 5^b + 6^a 13^b}, 
    Rationalize[{415.3, 407.85, 397.34, 396.04, 379.04}, 0]]], 
  1/4 <= a <= 3, -3 <= b <= -(1/4)}, {a, b}]` returns, in particular, `2^(2 Conjugate[a] + 3 Conjugate[b])` and similar expressions.

Comment: `NMaximize[{RealAbs[
   Correlation[{5 2^(2 a + 3 b), 2^(1 + a) 5^b, 3 2^(2 a + 3 b), 
     2^a 5^b, 2^(1 + b) 3^a 5^b + 6^a 13^b}, {415.3, 407.85, 397.34, 
     396.04, 379.04}]], -3 <= a <= 3, -3 <= b <= 3}, {a, b}, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` performs `{0.975188, {a -> 0.870872, b -> -3.}}`.

Comment: Response to user64494: Thanks for your comments. `NMaximize[{RealAbs[Correlation[{5 2^(2 a + 3 b), 2^(1 + a) 5^b, 3 2^(2 a + 3 b), 2^a 5^b, 2^(1 + b) 3^a 5^b + 6^a 13^b}, {415.3, 407.85, 397.34, 396.04, 379.04}]], -3 <= a <= 3, -3 <= b <= 3}, {a, b},   Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` gives the following error: "NMaximize::nnum: The function value -RealAbs[-0.559535] is not a number at {a,b} = {2.91862,2.07031}".

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Because you don't give Mathematica exact numbers (try `Rationalize[{415.3, ...}]` – it won't give you a result), [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) automatically reverts to `NMaximize` (see _Details and Options_). And as explained in the documentation for [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) under _Possible Issues_, for some methods, the result may only be a local maximum. Choosing another method gives the correct result as shown by @user64494.

Comment: Tona(@ does not work.):Works well for me in 13.3.1 on Windows 10. Also "NMaximize::nnum: The function value -RealAbs[-0.559535] is not a number at {a,b} = {2.91862,2.07031}" is a warning, not an error. Did you try to execute the code on a fresh kernel?

Comment: Response to Domen and user64494: Thanks a lot for your kind help. Following the advice of user64494, I executed the suggested code on a fresh kernel and I got the desired output. I also found the comment of Domen very useful. Thanks again.

Comment: Please consider asking a new question for your most recent issue, instead of attaching it to this closed question.